# Where to find where a function originates in eclipse, using XML? (MAC)

Tags: xml, eclipse

Like the title says, I want to find out where a function has been created by clicking on an instance where it has been called.

I know you can do it on visual studio so I was wondering if there is an Eclipse way of doing this.

So if I write a function called "LoginUser" which logs a user in, and then I call it, can I do something to that function call to find out where that function was written?

I have tried researching online and fiddling about but I cant find a solution.

Comment: What has XML got to do with this? What programming language?

Comment: We use XML to make testing Scripts where i work.

Comment: That still doesn't explain what XML has to do with your question. Are you asking about an XML file which contains bits of Java (or whatever language you are asking about)?

Comment: We write our code in XML, and we use eclipse. We have multiple files containing XML code, Im looking to find out if there is a way to navigate this code better. So if we have a test that checks if the app will let us log in, we will have a log in function. This log in function will be based in a different file and called in this test. I want to find an easy way to find where the function is based.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing a Java class you can press CRTL and hover over the method. A popup should open with the option to open the declaration or implementation of the method. Or you could just press "F3" (that is the default keybinding).